# Can I fly with white powder in a transparent bag?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airport-security, drugs

Instead of plain old coffee, I sometimes like to get my daily caffeine ration from other drinks, e.g. fruit juice. For this purpose I have bought some pure caffeine, which takes the form of white powder.

Now I'd like to take some of that on a journey where I go by plane. I don't want to take the big glass jar of caffeine with me, so the best thing I found is a small transparent bag. It looks somewhat like [this](http://img1.tradeget.com/hongjint%5CLQXRARO511.jpg).

[image: powder]

Now I assume this must look pretty suspicious, so I was wondering if your average European airport has the means to identify this as something harmless quickly or if I could expect hours of trouble if this bag were be detected.

Comment: I traveled with a similar bag with baking soda that I use as a toothpaste and had no problems in airports through europe, north america and central america.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but one alternative is to get some caffeine in pill form. Aside from being less suspicious when travelling you're also less likely to kill yourself with an accidental overdose which is exceedingly easy when it comes to pure caffeine.

Comment: I have flown in Europe with various white consumable powders in very smilar bags and nobody has seemed to care. Presumably even if someone did take a look, they have ways of differentiating between drugs and random powder. What I can advise you is to double bag your powder - in case the bag rubs against something and breaks, you still have another bag inside, so less likely to have a spill all over the inside of your luggage.

Comment: @helm - Follow my steps and you will be home free -

Comment: @user4050 - To be honest, depending on your race & color of skin and racial profiling bias in the minds of authorities it can be luck of the draw. So, the answer I posted will help who might get pulled to the side

Comment: @Sander + 1 on the double bag.

Comment: @user4050 Baking soda is not an organic chemical so would show up differently to caffeine.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. From now on, whenever I'm not in hurry, I'll travel with a bag of powder and dodgy looking pills... :)

Comment: My advice: Just don't do this.  It can wait til later.

Comment: the simple bottom line is carry **labelled**, **packaged** stuff to avoid headaches

Comment: My dad came back from Colombia once with unmarked sealed bags which contained coffee grounds and didn't have any problems even though they looked like they could have been bricks of cocaine. I'm sure the airport dogs sniffed it and didn't care.

Comment: A manufacturer's container and labeling would certainly be prefered but barring that, there are a lot of troubles you can avoid by at least making your own labels.  It would make clear what you claim to have.  Package it like this and it's like you're daring them to search you.

Comment: Related story: http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2015/08/29/methylamphetamine-epsom-salts-maryborough-queensland-australia-drugs-jail-police_n_8058246.html?utm_hp_ref=uk

Comment: @JoeBlow surely labeling drugs as "Not drugs" doesn't work?! Also can you even buy pure caffeine!?

Comment: I meant the official, brand, store-bought labels - the manufacturer's labels.

Comment: A long time ago, I was a long haired hippie and I wanted to enter Switzerland with a friend. We obviously matched some profile and were selected for careful screening. Turns out the milk powder packets we had with us had broken, so the first thing she opened produced a cloud of white powder. We thought this was hilarious and when she opened our dirty socks next, we were let go without further questions...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That bag would show orange color on an x-ray machine which is the color for organic material (on most machines) and it would be very obvious even between layers of clothing which are also organic but would show a different shade(powder bag would be a very dark shade of orange). If I looked at your bag for a fraction of a second I would most likely pull it out for physical inspection and then it really depends on the person who would deal with you and ask questions.

The amount of time you spend there really depends a lot on your profile (like it or not but that is how it works) and the answers you provide if your bag gets pulled out for further investigation.

My advise to you would be to carry your coffee powder in the manufacturer's packaging. Keep it sealed if possible.

Source : I  worked for North West Airlines as a Ground security coordinator in the past.

Answer (score 25):

It's possible that it might cause some concern given that it's unlabelled and white (that dodgy anthrax scare a few years back has done so much damage to air travel...sigh).

However, most airports in Europe you just stroll through and don't have to get checked, quite often.  If asked to declare, I'd be up front about it and mention it, rather than have them find it and cause  concern.

As far as scanning goes, they've been scanning powder for years.  I can't find an equivalent EU document, but the USA's TSA blog has [an entire post about travelling with powder](http://blog.tsa.gov/2009/09/new-procedures-for-traveling-with.html).  It's worth a read.

Short version: travelling with powder is common.  They have easy ways to test it for explosives.  Inspections on powder are few and far between, and there is NO ban on travelling with powder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was worried less about explosives, I think the amount is too small for anyone to care. But I guess it could get mistaken for cocaine or something like that.

Comment: @helm yeah, I travel with a lot of medicines, and always just declare them (often as 'drugs' which gets attention!). 95% of the time they don't even want to look at them, they're happy to just wave me through.

Comment: [New link to TSA post](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2009/09/08/new-procedures-traveling-powders)

Answer (score 10):

Hard to tell. I do take a bunch of prescription drugs that I have consolidated into a single small zip lock bag for travel and that really looked fairly suspicious. No problems whatsoever in a 100+ domestic+international flights.

Then again, your bag looks even more suspicious and a lot depends on how you may show up against expectations and profiles. This may be easier to pull off when you are a frequent flyer middle aged fat white guy than if you are a first ticket dark skinned young adult from the middle east or mexico.

Best bet would be to check with the airline first and be really upfront about it in security: Toss the bag into a large bin on it's own and then be prepared to answer the questions you'll get.

Comment: It really depends on what country you're in. I don't know about Europe but if you're flying through the Middle East with a bag full of unlabeled, mixed pills, you stand a high chance of at least getting fined and the pills confiscated, and there's a chance you could be arrested. Some countries take that way more seriously than others.

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid bringing samples of pure caffeine on aircraft because caffeine is somewhat toxic (1-10 g) and therefore is probably prohibited by flight regulations.

Source: http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/05/18/caffeine-powder-poses-deadly-risks-2/

Answer (score 4):

Always carry:

- Labels
- Prescriptions

Even if its in weird packets.

I traveled quite a bit with herbal medicines that always raise issues:

- Powders
- Unmarked brownish/ olive/ sandy colored Pills in similar small plastic
- Herbal oils

So, I carry:

- labels inside/ stuck on each little plastic sachet or bottle
- Detailed written Prescription from doctors
- Printed & signed detailed affidavit letter from doctor
- Smaller legit looking plastic bottles/ cases/ packets

From Parminders answer:

> My advise to you would be to carry your coffee powder in the
>   manufacturer's packaging. Keep it sealed if possible.

Exactly the reason why printed labels and such will help.

Usually this wont cause issues but having all this helps calm down the authorities.

Answer (score 4):

The average European airport security is only marginally more patient than the TSA. That is to say, they are mini-dictators in their little realm. On top of that, they're paranoid, overworked and hated by all. It's not a productive mix.

If they see this —and they will— they will inspect it. Some might buy that it's caffeine. Some wont. Nobody can tell you how many that number will be but flights are expensive so **it really only takes one guard having a bad day to ruin yours**.

If you get stopped by *that* guard, do you really expect they'll submit it to a substance test **before** they decide whether or not to pull you off your flight? No. You'll be arrested on suspicion and held while it is tested.

If you ***need*** caffeine regularly, buy some tablets (ie Pro Plus) and leave them in their blister-packs, in their boxes. Take them whole or crush them when you get to the other side. Otherwise just wait until you get to a pharmacy and buy new supplies.

Answer (score 1):

I've carried on a container of white powder in the US and China, nobody has taken note of it.  I've also carried multiple pounds of white powder still sealed in properly labeled manufactures packaging.

That being said, I wouldn't bring a bag of powder, period.  Put it in something more substantial!